# Injective map from the Cartesian product of two sylow-p-subgroups into the group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a group of order 148. Show that $G$ is not simple.

The given solution goes as follows:
$148 = 4 × 37$. By Sylow’s theorem, it has at least one subgroup $P$ of order 37. If $P'$ is another, then $P ∩ P'$ is just the identity, since its order must properly divided the prime number 37. Then the map $P×P' → G$ is injective, which is not possible, since $37^2$ is larger than 148. In particular, every conjugate of P is again just P, so P is normal and G is not simple.

Could someone help me with understanding the line "Then the map $P×P' → G$ is injective".[Source](https://math.berkeley.edu/~ogus/Math_113_08/supplements/solsylow.pdf) to question 7.4,9.

My very bad intuitive understanding tells me that it has something to do with the the product of any two elements from $P$ and $P'$ respectively is unique in $G$. But I don't know why. (Or even if I am on track).

Comment: One can identify the set $PP'$ with $P\times P'$ due to the intersection being trivial. I have no idea why it is phrased as it is, rather than just directly using the size of the set $PP'$.

Comment: As an aside: Were those few lines really too much to type here to make the question self-contained?

Comment: Ok so for all $p \in P$ and $p' \in P'$, $p.p'$, then $p.p' \not\in P$ and $p.p' \not\in P'$. But say given $a \in P$ and $b \in P'$ where $p \not = a$ and $p' \not = b$ how can you be sure that $p.p' \not = a.b$?

Comment: And you are right. I will add the details now.

Comment: You should know (since this is a basic result everyone should be taught early) that if $A$ and $B$ are subgroups then $|AB| = \frac{|A||B|}{|A\cap B|}$.

Comment: If $pp' = ab$, then $a^{-1}p = bp'^{-1}$. The LHS is in $P$, and the RHS is in $P'$, and so both sides are in the intersection, which is trivial. So $p = a$, contradiction.